# Webpage doesn't display C# HTML POST

Tags: c#, php, html, post, get

I try to display a value sent with C# HTML Post on my `xampp` webpage, here is my code:

```
private void sendHtmlData(UInt16 value) {
  var postData = "Package" + value.ToString()
  var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/dashboard/");
  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
  request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  request.ContentLength = data.Length;
  using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
  }
  var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
}

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <? echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["Package"]); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why does this not work? E.g nothing happens on my webpage if i call the function.

Answer (score 1):

There are two fails:

1-Post data must be in form *key=value* but you're just concatenating the key with the value, you missed the "=", change

```
var postData = "Package" + value.ToString();
```

to

```
var postData = "Package=" + value.ToString();
```

Also it will be recommended to urlencode the value in case it has any special char:

```
var postData = "Package=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(value.ToString());
```

2-If you send the data as POST then you must retrieve it as POST, not as GET, change

```
<? echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["Package"]); ?>
```

to

```
<? echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["Package"]); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but nothing happens on my webpage.

Comment: Where are you looking at your web page?

Comment: So what's the content of "responseString"?

Comment: The HTML of my webpage.

Comment: `<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body><? echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["Package"]); ?></body>
</html>`

Comment: If that's the content then your server is not processing the php code, you must revise your server's configuration.

Comment: Okay, i think i forgot the `PHP` tag, so this is my code now:
`<?PHP $Lbl = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Package"]);?>`
Now the responseString contains "23" but my webpage shows a notice:
`Notice: Undefined index: Package in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 6`

Comment: I am not sure if it is acutally possible to display the transmitted data without any interaction from the user? If i type manually: `127.0.0.1/index.php/?Package=HelloWorld` everything works. But i don't want to do it manually.

Comment: Ok, now we're getting to what I supposed. So, you want app A to communicate with server B while client C has the page open on B, and you want that when A sends data to B, C gets automatically refreshed?

Comment: Yes, that's what i thought about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107889/discussion-between-gusman-and-binarybigint).